# how to take directory access control with nginx conf

Tags: nginx

I'm using linux. there are some domains, such as the follow:

```
/home/wwwroot/aaa.com
/home/wwwroot/bbb.com
/home/wwwroot/ccc.com

FILE1: /home/wwwroot/aaa.com/get.php
FILE2:/home/wwwroot/bbb.com/config.php
```

in FILE1, I wrote:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('/home/wwwroot/bbb.com/config.php');
echo $data; //i can get the data.
?>
```

I think is unsafe. could you please tell me how to config with nignx config that the domain only allow to acces its directory.?

Comment: are you using php5-fpm ?

Comment: output is the php code in that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so here's what you need to do, we need to create separate pools for those 2 websites, pools are located inside `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/`, by default you'll find pool called `www.conf`, you'll copy that file and create a new pool, then edit the file and rename the `[www]` to any other name, that's the pool name, and change the listening sock file or port ( which ever you use ).

Then we need to add `open_basedir` to each pool,

```
php_admin_value[open_basedir] = /home/wwwroot/aaa.com/
```

And `bbb.com` in the other file, then inside the nginx config pass each virtual host to the according pool.

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad AbuShady! I think it can solve my problem.(keywords "open_basedir nginx")

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
location /users {
  alias   /var/www/student/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri index;
}
```

Create new location and alias new project public. It's works for with Nginx and Thin conbination with Ruby on rails.